# I want to display start and end date of a list by reading the dates from 2 textviews(Datepickers)

Tags: android

HERE I TRIED SOMETHING............................SOMEBODY HELP . when i try to read the date from those field it throws error..

```
    private void CalculateDates1() {//this functio is to calculate dates from the text fields
    DateRange = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean loopVal = true;
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    String str=ETFROM.getText().toString();
    String str1=ETTO.getText().toString();

    // textView is the TextView view that should display it

    String StartDate = formatter.format(str);
    String EndDate = formatter.format(str1);


    DateRange.add(StartDate);
    Date date =null;

    try {
        while (loopVal) {


            date = formatter.parse(StartDate);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            cal.setTime(date);
            if (StartDate.equals(EndDate)) {
                loopVal = false;
            } else {
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                StartDate = formatter.format(cal.getTime());
                DateRange.add(StartDate);
            }
```

can any on help pls.....

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You have only posted code. Please explain your problem.

Comment: i think she want all dates between two date which is in two textview .One text view shows  start date and other shows end date

Comment: It exactly throws error in this line  String StartDate = formatter.format(str);

Comment: can you post what error you're getting? logcat?

Comment: @lakshmi see my answer hope its help you.

Answer (score 0):

You get error because format of date which you pass in formatter is not same as you define in SimpleDateFormat. you have to pass same format as you define in Simple date format then it will format date.

Then other solution for get all dates between start date and end dates use below function.

```
    public  ArrayList<Date> getDates(String dateString1, String dateString2)
{
    ArrayList<Date> dates = new ArrayList<Date>();
    DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date date1 = null;
    Date date2 = null;

    try {
        date1 = df1 .parse(dateString1);
        date2 = df1 .parse(dateString2);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(date1);


    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date2);

    while(!cal1.after(cal2))
    {
        dates.add(cal1.getTime());
        cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return dates;
}
```

**NOTE:** Make sure you have pass parameter for dates is same as i have set in SimpleDateFormat else whatever format you want to pass that format replace with SimpleDateFormat